# Catch Interrupted system call in threading

Tags: python, multithreading, asyncsocket

I have a client-server application using envisage framework, I'm using threads to handle the connection, here is a token from the code

```
    ....
    SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True        
    self.server = TCPFactory( ( HOST, PORT ), TCPRequestHandler, self.application)               

    self.server_thread = threading.Thread( target = self.server.serve_forever )        

    self.server_thread.setDaemon( True )       
    self.server_thread.start() 

class TCPFactory( SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer ):    
    def __init__( self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, application ):
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__( self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass )
        self.application = application

class TCPRequestHandler( SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):
    """"""
    def setup( self ):
        .....
```

In the envisage framework I call the `open_file( )` function, which give us a popup window, but when this window appear than I'm receiving the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: The snippet from the code isn't very helpful as it does not have to do anything with the stack trace you pasted below (nor with the call to `open_file()` you mention).  And do you have any idea what could have interrupted the `select()` call mentioned in the trace?

Comment: Usually, "Interrupted system call" is an error that should be handled by retrying the system call.  It's unclear to me why select.select() is not doing the retrying itself.  You need to catch the 'select.error', check that its errno attribute is equal to errno.EINTR, and if yes, just ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Armin Rigo comment, I modified the SockeServer.py

```
def serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):
        """Handle one request at a time until shutdown.

        Polls for shutdown every poll_interval seconds. Ignores
        self.timeout. If you need to do periodic tasks, do them in
        another thread.
        """
        self.__is_shut_down.clear()
        try:
            while not self.__shutdown_request:
                # XXX: Consider using another file descriptor or
                # connecting to the socket to wake this up instead of
                # polling. Polling reduces our responsiveness to a
                # shutdown request and wastes cpu at all other times.
                try:
                        r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
                except select.error  as ex:
                        #print ex
                        if ex[0] == 4:
                                continue
                        else:
                                raise  
                if self in r:
                    self._handle_request_noblock()
        finally:
            self.__shutdown_request = False
            self.__is_shut_down.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem when I added a little httpd server to a program, it receives various signals from other processes. After playing around I came up with a simple solution that avoids actually modifying stlib code, but I'm thinking it's a little risky. I simply wrapped the serve_forever call in a loop that catches and ignores socket errors:

```
def non_int_serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):
   while 1:
        try:
            self.serve_forever(poll_interval=poll_interval)
            break
        except select.error:
            pass
```

This removes the risk of needing different solutions for different versions of SocketServer.py, but it's not obvious that serve_forever() should be restartable multiple times, even though it appears to work now.

Any thoughts?